# Maven deploy plugin - deployAtEnd not working

Tags: maven, maven-deploy-plugin

I'm using maven-deploy-plugin in multi-module project with `deployAtEnd` property set to `true`.

After executing `mvn deploy` in root project, deploy plugin is executed for each subproject - I can see something like:

`[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) @ subproject-name ---
[INFO] Deploying package:subproject-name:v1.1 at end`

Last invocation is for root project:

`[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) @ parent-project ---
[INFO] Deploying package:parent-project:v1.1 at end`

and that's all, actual deployment is not executed.

How do I make deploy plugin work correctly in multi-module project with `deployAtEnd=true`?

Comment: And at the end of all modules you don't see an output deploying the artifacts to a repository ? Are you using custom maven plugins which define their own life cycle?

Comment: @khmarbaise Correct, there's no output related to deployment. I'm not using any custom plugins (at least I think so, how can I verify that?)

Comment: Can you show the full log output otherwise it's hard to see what's wrong?

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm preparing some minimal example. Meanwhile, I noticed that if I put explicit execution in plugin definition: 
`<executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>`, 
then deployment starts, but at some subproject in the middle of the sequence.

Comment: To be clear i'm using deployAtEnd for a long time with large projects about 500 modules which works without any problem.....So i assume there is some other problem..which i can only take a look at if you offer the appropriate log files ...

Answer (score 7):

As we just ran into this issue today, I found the related issue in maven-deploy-plugin:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/MDEPLOY-193

**Jérôme Joslet explantation in this issue :**

> I issue this problem today and found a workaround.
>
> The maven-deploy-plugin records its state in static variables. One for
>   stacking deploy requests (`deployRequests`) and another one for counting
>   ready project (`readyProjectsCounter`). When the problem occurs, there
>   is more than one static variable used to count ready projects. This
>   happens when there is more than one classloader that loads the deploy
>   plugin's classes. This leads to multiple class instances and multiple
>   static variable instances. Some module count on one instance and
>   others modules on another one.
>
> The result is that the deploy plugin
>   never flush its pending deploy requests since no counter is equal to
>   the number of project in the reactor.
>
> As mentionned in the following
>   documentation : https://svn.apache.org/repos/infra/websites/production/maven/content/reference/maven-classloading.html :
>
> *For projects that use build extensions, plugin classloaders are
>   wired to project classloaders. This gives plugin code access to both
>   Maven API packages and packages exported by the project build
>   extensions. Maven will create one and only one classloader for each
>   unique plugin+dependencies+build-extensions combination.*
>
> and
>
> *Maven guarantees there will be one and only one project classloader for each
>   unique set of project build extensions and the same classloader will
>   be used by all projects that have the set of build extensions.*
>
> The workaround is to declare all extension plugins, with all their extra
>   `<dependencies>`, in the parent project. This assures that the same
>   classloader is used for loading plugin in all modules.

Comment: If you are in a situation with a long chain of parent projects (don't ask...): go up the chain until you reach the first project defining plugins. 

Projects only defining plugin _management_ can be safely ignored.

Answer (score 3):

Today I resolved the same problem in my project.

The problem modules have extensions (`<extension>` tags). They violate a counter of built modules in maven-deploy-plugin.

**To fix it I moved `<extension>` to the root POM.**