# using maven-deploy for freestyle projects

Tags: maven, jenkins-job-builder

I am in the process converting existing maven projects to freestyle projects, where the post-build step to deploy to repository are used only with `maven` project.

what is the equivalent for implementing the below with a freestyle project type. Is there any way to directly use `mvn deploy` as a postbuild step to push the artifacts at the end of a build to the artifact server (nexus) ?

Now for instance when you run the following example with JJB, you can see job gets updated, but the `Deploy Artifacts to maven repository` is displayed for a freestyle project type but does not work as expected, since its used only with a maven project type.

```
- job:
    name: test-freestyle
    project-type: freestyle
    description: 'example for freestyle'
    builders:
        - shell: |
            echo 'Hello world'
            cat /etc/passwd
    publishers:
        - maven-deploy:
            id: example
            url: http://repo.example.com/maven2/
            unique-version: true
            deploy-unstable: false
            release-env-var: TIMER
```

Answer (score 0):

The working solution I found was to use a `- maven-target` under the builder section as follows:

```
- job:
    name: test-freestyle
    project-type: freestyle
    description: 'example for freestyle'
    builders:
        - shell: |
            echo 'Hello world'
            cat /etc/passwd
        - maven-target:
            maven-version: '{mvn33}'
            pom: pom.xml'
            goals: 'clean install deploy -DdeployAtEnd=true ...'
            settings: '{mvn-settings}'
```

Note: Found that the maven deploy plugin has some [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328154/maven-deploy-plugin-deployatend-not-working) uploading the artifacts when `DeployAtEnd` option is used, in that case simple use `deploy` without the option.