# installAtEnd and deployAtEnd are Not Executed at End of Build

Tags: maven, tycho, maven-bom

I have a multi-module project with a structure like this:

- build

  - module
  - module.bom
  - rcp.build

    - module.rcp

Both build projects where separate before and worked. Now that I put them together `installAtEnd` and `deployAtEnd` do not work. I added them like this:

```
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <installAtEnd>true</installAtEnd>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <deployAtEnd>true</deployAtEnd>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

I did not configure the plug-ins beyond the above. Still whenever I run the build I get the following log:

```
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ module.rcp ---
[INFO] Installing group:module.rcp:0.1.6-SNAPSHOT at end
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) @ module.rcp ---
[INFO] Deploying group:module.rcp:0.1.6-SNAPSHOT at end
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] modules ............................................. SUCCESS [  3.339 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:05 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-01-18T12:54:18+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Maven forgot to install / deploy.

I found [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEPLOY-193) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328154/maven-deploy-plugin-deployatend-not-working), which suggest it might be due to Tycho. So I added the Tycho plug-ins to the parent *pom.xml* which did nothing. Then I removed the RCP module entirely. Still the same problem.

Now the BOM still has a parent that is not the Maven project "build", and removing it / changing the parent makes the build install and deploy correctly. However since it's a BOM I can't use the "build" parent.

Is there any other way to get `installAtEnd` and `deployAtEnd` to work in my project structure?

Comment: This can't be working cause installAtEnd/deployAtEnd won't work correct for different packaging like Tycho. If need a working solution for such cases please take a look at: https://github.com/khmarbaise/maven-deployer-extension

Comment: @khmarbaise As I said in the question, I removed the Tycho module and the error persisted. In fact, I already know (and stated) the problem is the BOM and its parent POM being different. (And FYI it does work without the BOM but with Tycho.)

Comment: @khmarbaise But your Maven plug-in still works for the BOM, so thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) pointed out, the following Maven extension can be used: https://github.com/khmarbaise/maven-deployer-extension

Note that this approach won't work on a Jenkins, since it doesn't [support Maven core extensions](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30058). (I'd say "yet", but JENKINS-30058 is a 4 year old blocker bug, so I suppose it's not going to be fixed any time soon.) If the build should work on Jenkins, too, there seems to be no other option than either disabling `deployAtEnd` and `installAtEnd`  or to remove the second parent POM from the modules.

---

Today I found another reason for the build to not deploy while maintaining an older project. There was something like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
```

Removing the `<extensions>` made the project deploy again.